# Rock Paper Scissors JS Game

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner with JS and I'm struggling to understand the logic with this one. Nothing is being logged in the console, although I am getting the alert inputs. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Is it perhaps something to do with scope? I feel like this should be really simple but I can't get it working.

```
function computerPlay() {
    const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    let result = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
    return result;
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    let selection = prompt('Please enter your selection');
    let playerScore = 0;
    let computerScore = 0;
    let result = "";

    computerSelection = computerPlay();

    playerSelection = selection.toLowerCase();
    if (playerSelection == 'rock') {
        if (computerSelection == 'rock') {
            return ["It's a draw!", playerScore + 1, computerScore + 1];
        } else if (computerSelection == 'paper') {
            return ["You lose!", computerScore + 1];
        } else {
            return ["You win!", computerScore + 1];
        }
    } else if (playerSelection == 'paper') {
        if (computerSelection == 'paper') {
            return "It's a draw!";
        } else if (computerSelection == 'scissors') {
            return "Computer wins!";
        } else {
            return "You win!";
        }
    } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors') {
        if (computerSelection == 'scissors') {
            return "It's a draw!"
        } else if (computerSelection == 'rock') {
            return "Computer wins!"
        } else {
            return "You win!"
        }
    }

    return result + "Player Score = " + playerScore + "Computer Score = " + computerScore;

}

function game() {

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        computerPlay();
        playRound();
    }

}

console.log(game())
```

Comment: One thing where you go wrong is that `game()` doesn't `return` anything, so logging `undefined` should be expected.

Comment: Also, look at `switch` statements instead of all those `if` statements.

Comment: if the user makes a valid selection in `playround()` will never return the last line. the function stops running as soon as it hits the first return statement.

Comment: There's also a ton of simplifications you can do to the logic. The three seconds are extremely repetitive - there's a strong, a weak and an equal in every case.

Comment: there's no reason to call `computerPlay();` inside `game()` since it's called in `playRound();`

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I see, thanks for that - this is an issue I've not came across yet, how would you go about amending the code so that I can return the scores as well?

Answer (score 1):

Move your console log from where it is to inside the `game()` function like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(playRound());
}
```

You also don't need to call `computerPlay()` in the game function, as it is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the game function this way.

```
function game() {

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const result = playRound();
      console.log(result)
  }

}
game()
```

Then you call game(). You will be able to see your console log and also you do not need to call the computerPlay function inside the game function. It's functionality is already called in the playRound function. Hope this helps cheers

Comment: Thanks, do you know why I can't return or console.log this line? `return result + "Player Score = " + playerScore + "Computer Score = " + computerScore;`